# Interface Mock gevis nullpointer exception

Tags: java, junit

I'm a bit new to unittesting, but I try to mock an interface. It gives a nullpointer in the setup. Can anyone help me mock these objects?

Here is the code:

```
public class ClassToTest
        {

            @Mock private RequestContainer request;
            @Mock URL serviceEndPoint;
            @Mock HttpURLConnection connection;

            @Before
            public void setup() {
                try
                {  
                    //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // tried this, but failes because mockito can't mock url.
                    when(request.getServiceEndpoint()).thenReturn(serviceEndPoint); //nullpointer here
                }
                catch(MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    // setup failed!
                    assertTrue("setup failed, unable to create mock for service endpoint....", false);
                }    
            }
    }
```

---

```
 public interface RequestContainer
            {
                public String getJson() throws JsonProcessingException;
                public String getRequestMethod();
                public String getWebsiteKey();
                public String getSecretKey();
                public URL getServiceEndpoint() throws MalformedURLException;
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered removing `@Mock` from `URL serviceEndPoint`, and just instantiating it by hand?

Comment: Yes, but later on I want to open a connection to the endpoint (from this url). Since I don't want to actually open the connection I want the URL object mocked... In one of the tests I use this: when(serviceEndPoint.openConnection()).thenReturn(connection);

Comment: The `connection` won't "actually" be opened - it's a mock.

Comment: I want it to be a mock, but mockito can't do that... apperently...

Comment: Mockito can't mock the `URL` because it's `final`; it can mock the `HttpURLConnection` because it's not `final`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `// tried this, but failes because mockito can't mock url.`

So, don't ask mockito to mock a URL. Mockito can't mock `final` classes.

- Remove `@Mock` from the `URL serviceEndPoint` field;
- Reinstate the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` line
- Immediately after, write `serviceEndPoint = new URL("http://example.com");`.

The `example.com` domain is [guaranteed not to be assigned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) (by RFC), so you'd never end up talking to a real server if you accidentally didn't mock the `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Thank you, this get's me a bit further. But when serviceEndPoint is a valid url instance... how can I mock this: when(serviceEndPoint.openConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
It does not work right now, because serviceEndPoint is not a Mock anymore

Comment: You might need to use [PowerMockito](http://vaguehope.com/2012/02/powermock-puzzler/).

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't really want to... ClassToTest is officially the class making the actual connection and executing the request, so I wanted to have this class making the connection, but I can change the interface from public URL getServiceEndpoint() to public HttpURLConnection  getServiceConnection(). This would make it eassier to test I think?